# download in one click issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, download, uibutton, nsurlconnection

i want to download file from web server and for that I need
1. send request for file path to web service method
2. receive this path on iphone side
3. now convert this path into NSURL
4. and finally send the request to web server for file download

right now i am doing all above but user have to
1. GetURL button and then
2. Download button

I want all this in one button click.

I tried for this too but problem is:

```
DownlloadButtonClick  
{  
   [self getURL];  
   [self DownloadFile];  
} 
getURL{  
    soapmsg  
    NSURL  
    NSURLReuest  
    ...  
    ..  
    ..  
}
```

//after this i was expecting that connection should be done and data(filepath) will be received, 
but this not happen

after `getURL()` method its back to above and call `DownloadFile()` and then app will crash...
app is crash this is accepted as i know its depend on `getURL()` method..

now my problem is where should i place `getURL()` method and `DownloadFile()` method so i can execute both on one click

thank you in advance

Comment: Your question ('que'?) is hard to answer as it isn't very well stated. And your app is crashing but this isn't actually the problem?

Comment: right my app is crashing and thats not problem for me because i know why this happen but my main problem is i want to do all 4 (or you can say execute 2 methods )steps in one click...

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your hard to decipher question correctly...

Your problem seems to be that you want to do an asynchronous action - getURL - and then when that has completed, another action. In your DownlloadButtonClick method, you want to think about only calling getURL (and not DownloadFile yet). In whatever code you have for handling the result of getURL (i.e. the URL has been fetched), you can then kick off your DownloadFile action.

Comment: i did this, -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser   
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName   
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI   
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName  
{   
 if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"getURLResponse"])  
 {  
  NSLog(@"soapResults : %@",soapResults);  
  UrlForDownload = soapResults;  
  soapResults=nil;  
  [self DownloadFile];  
    }   
}  
if i am doing so app is crashing

Comment: You don't want to kick off something like a sychronous download right in the middle of some XML parsing code, which may already be on the main runloop. How does DownloadFile work? Is it synchronous or asynchronous? If it is synchronous, you want to *not* be doing that on the main thread.

Comment: I'm trying to help you help yourself here, so without pasting more code, can you tell me if the fragment you posted is synchronous or asynchronous? If you don't understand those concepts, you should make sure you do, as it will be of use to you in the future.

Comment: Ok, cool, it is asynchronous. "Chaining" your communications so that the result of the first request coming back kicks off your second request is the way to go. I'm afraid I have no idea why your app is crashing and with the very limited info you provide, I can't help any further. The more info you provide in your questions, and the more clearly you state them, the more other people will be able to help you. I strongly recommend reading at least some of this: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: In fact, before looking at the above link, check out this one first: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx